# Loading Dojo dijit CSS from CDN

Tags: dojo

I am quite new to dojo world.
Using dojo with google's CDN is well and Fine. But while using dijit just dojo.require() does not work. Where can I find the default CSS Themes from CDN ??

and another question out of quorisity:
Would the the CSS configuration for dijit work for dojox too ??

Comment: I've got aol's CDNs for CSS but.
Can I get them from Google too ??
or Google doesn't provide services for CSS

Comment: AOL and Google deploy the same "cross domain" build of Dojo, which includes all the CSS for Dijit and DojoX.  They are referenced over http like any other file.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The CSS can be found on Google's CDN. I've used it in a page or two. Here's some CSS link tags.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.4/dojo/resources/dojo.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.4/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css">
```

Much like the libraries, you can pick a more or less specific version in the URL, so this will grab the latest in the 1.4.x chain.

**UPDATED [19/May/2016]:-**

Update version - 1.10.4

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/resources/dojo.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css">
```

Comment: Folder structure it works for 1.6.1
`http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6.1/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css`

Comment: This post comes pretty high on google for this question, so I add the 1.8 Version as well:


`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css"/>`

Comment: And here's the latest 1.10: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css"/>`

Comment: I'm here to add version 1.12: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.12.3/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" />`

Answer (score 12):

Here is 1.9.1.

Theme Tester: [Claro](http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.9.1/dojo-release-1.9.1/dijit/themes/themeTester.html?theme=claro), [Tundra](http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.9.1/dojo-release-1.9.1/dijit/themes/themeTester.html?theme=tundra), [Nihilo](http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.9.1/dojo-release-1.9.1/dijit/themes/themeTester.html?theme=nihilo), and [Soria](http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.9.1/dojo-release-1.9.1/dijit/themes/themeTester.html?theme=soria)

- Claro - http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.1/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css
- Tundra - http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.1/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css
- Nihilo - http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.1/dijit/themes/nihilo/nihilo.css
- Soria - http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.1/dijit/themes/soria/soria.css

Answer (score 2):

Here is 1.10.4.

Theme Tester: [Claro](http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.10.4/dojo-release-1.10.4/dijit/themes/themeTester.html?theme=claro), [Tundra](http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.10.4/dojo-release-1.10.4/dijit/themes/themeTester.html?theme=tundra), [Nihilo](http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.10.4/dojo-release-1.10.4/dijit/themes/themeTester.html?theme=nihilo), [Soria](http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.10.4/dojo-release-1.10.4/dijit/themes/themeTester.html?theme=soria)

- Claro https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css
- Tundra https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css
- Nihilo https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dijit/themes/nihilo/nihilo.css
- Soria https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dijit/themes/soria/soria.css

Answer (score 0):

Well, As we know ***`1.11.2`*** version also has been released so below are the cdn links for that-

- **Claro:** https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.11.2/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css
- **Tundra:** https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.11.2/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css
- **Nihilo:** https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.11.2/dijit/themes/nihilo/nihilo.css
- **Soria:** https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.11.2/dijit/themes/soria/soria.css

***Hoping this will help you :)***