# What libraries does Google host (other than jQuery)?

Tags: jquery, cdn

First, I apology if I used the wrong term in the question (Please feel free to edit if I'm wrong).

I know Google hosts (almost) all version of jQuery, jQuery UI (js and css)

For example :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

or for CSS :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" />
```

My question is : **Does it host other library? Useful plugin as jQuery UI? Other templace or CSS?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Available Libraries](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries):

- Chrome Frame
- Dojo
- Ext Core
- jQuery
- jQuery UI
- MooTools
- Prototype
- script_aculo_us
- SWFObject
- Yahoo! User Interface Library (YUI)
- WebFont Loader

CSS files:

- [jquery UI](http://blog.jqueryui.com/2009/03/jquery-ui-17/)
- [Dojo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2899368/loading-dojo-dijit-css-from-cdn)
- [YUI](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/yui/2.8.0r4/build/reset-fonts-grids/reset-fonts-grids.css)

Comment: Dang! Searched everywhere to find that, even in the google API manual and couldn't find it! Thanks!

Comment: Do you have the same thing for CSS? (for example, `<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" />`)

Comment: jquery,css download from google: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/820412/jquery-css-download-from-google

Comment: Well, yeah, obviously, I knew about jQueryUI CSS theme... (see question + previous comment) I asked for the other libraries/plugin's css or template :) Nevertheless, the link can help others here again :)

Comment: Loading Dojo dijit CSS from CDN: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2899368/loading-dojo-dijit-css-from-cdn