# What libraries does the Google CDN host (besides jQuery)?

Tags: jquery, javascript, cdn

I've used this link that is suggested as a quick access link to jQuery from their homepage:

```
//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js
```

Is there a list of other supported JavaScript libraries besides jQuery?

Comment: It's not a "quick access link". A better question would be "What libraries does the Google CDN host (besides jQuery)?" Using such a question in a search - just try it verbatim as written! - will also yield better results. Using the correct terms is important to finding information.

Comment: Although Google's CDN is pretty reliable, an easy way to find if/where somewhere hosts a library is by Googling "LibraryName CDN" and you'll either get direct information or pages that explain about it

Comment: And look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4040837/what-libraries-does-google-host-other-than-jquery) someone else already wrote .. mind readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's supported by [Google Hosted Libraries](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide) which is a [content delivery network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network).
Currently available libraries are:

- AngularJS
- Chrome Frame
- Dojo
- Ext Core
- jQuery
- jQuery UI
- MooTools
- Prototype
- script_aculo_us
- SWFObject
- WebFont Loader

Answer (score 7):

The [**Google Hosted Libraries**](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide) is a CDN ([**content distribution network**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network)) for the most popular, open-source [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) libraries. The hosted libraries provides access to a growing list of the most popular, open-source JavaScript libraries, including:

- [**AngularJS**](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#angularjs) ([website](http://angularjs.org/))
- [**Chrome Frame**](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#chrome-frame) ([website](https://developers.google.com/chrome/chrome-frame/))
- [**Dojo**](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#dojo) ([website](http://dojotoolkit.org/))
- [**Ext Core**](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#ext-core) ([website](http://www.sencha.com/products/extcore/))
- [**jQuery**](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery) ([website](http://jquery.com/))
- [**jQuery UI**](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery-ui) ([website](http://jqueryui.com/))
- [**MooTools**](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#mootools) ([website](http://mootools.net/))
- [**Prototype**](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#prototype) ([website](http://prototypejs.org/))
- [**script.aculo.us**](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#scriptaculous) ([website](http://script.aculo.us/))
- [**SWFObject**](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#swfobject) ([website](https://code.google.com/p/swfobject/))
- [**WebFont Loader**](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#webfont) ([website](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/webfont_loader))

Google works directly with the key stake holders for each library effort and accepts the latest stable versions as they are released.

[*Source*](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/)

Answer (score 1):

[**Microsoft Ajax Content Delivery Network**](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/cdn.ashx)

The CDN hosts the following third party script libraries which have been uploaded, and are licensed to you, by the owners of those libraries:

- jQuery (www.jquery.com)
- jQuery UI (www.jqueryui.com)
- jQuery Mobile
  (www.jquerymobile.com)
- jQuery Validation (www.jquery.com)
- jQuery
  Cycle (www.malsup.com/jquery/cycle/)
- jQuery DataTables
  (http://datatables.net/)
- Ajax Control Toolkit (owned by the
  Outercurve Foundation – www.outercurve.org)

The Microsoft Ajax CDN also includes the following libraries which have been uploaded by Microsoft:

- ASP.NET Ajax
- ASP.NET MVC JavaScript Files
- ASP.NET SignalR JavaScript Files